# To add&remove nested(two-level) input elements dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I searched the question several times, but didn't get the solution, that's why I'm asking here. I already know how to add&remove one-level input elements, as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn_addOpt').click(function () {
            var opt = $('<div></div>');
            opt.append('<p>Answer:</p>');
            opt.append('<input type="text" name="lable[]">');
            $('#opt').append(opt);
        });
        $('#btn_removeOpt').click(function () {
            $('#opt div:last').remove();
        });             
    });
</script>
```

And the body of html is:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    What's the question?<br/>
    <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
    <input type="button" id="btn_addOpt" value="Add Answer"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn_removeOpt" value="Remove Answer"/><br/>
    <div id="opt"></div><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

The idea is when I click the 'Add Answer' button, a group of elements:

```
<p>Answer:</p>
<input type="text" name="lable[]">
```

will be added, and also will be removed after I click the 'Remove Answer' button. However, what I try to do is to take all elements above as a group, which inclues the:

```
What's the question?<br/>
<input type="text" name="name"/><br />
<input type="button" id="btn_addOpt" value="Add Answer"/>
<input type="button" id="btn_removeOpt" value="Remove Answer"/><br/>
<div id="opt"></div><br/>
```

And I try to add&remove this group dynamically. So I try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn_addQues').click(function () {
            var que = $('<div></div>');
            que.append('<p>What\'s the question?</p>');
            que.append('<input type="text" name="name"/>');
            que.append('<input type="button" id="btn_addOpt" value="Add Answer"/>');
            que.append('<input type="button" id="btn_removeOpt" value="Remove Answer"/><br/>');
            que.append('<div id="opt"></div><br/>');
            $('#question').append(que);
        });

        $('#btn_removeQues').click(function () {
            $('#question div:last').remove();
        })

        $('#btn_addOpt').click(function () {
            var opt = $('<div></div>');
            opt.append('<p>Answer:</p>');
            opt.append('<input type="text" name="lable[]">');
            $('#opt').append(opt);
        });

        $('#btn_removeOpt').click(function () {
            $('#opt div:last').remove();
        });             
    });
</script>
```

And the body become:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn_addQues" value="Add Question"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn_removeQues" value="Remove Question"/>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="question"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form> 
</body>
```

However, it can add&remove the whole group of elements dynamically, but inside the group, the "Add Answer" and "remove answer" buttons don't work. Seems there are some conflicts. Or there might be some other ways that can do it. Basically, What I try to do is to add&remove a group of elements by buttons, and inside the group there are also two buttons to add&remove some other input elements. So it's a nested(two-level) elements creation. And all information filled in will be posted to another page. I'm not sure if I explain clearly, but anyone could help? Please provide some codes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to rebind the onclick events to the new html elements created in your new group. So after copying the HTML, you would need to do $("#btn_addQues).click("etc..."), so you might want to think about creating reusable functions for them.

However, if you are going to use ids they need to be unique.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but do you mean that since it has multiple add&remove answer buttons. I should rebind an unique id for each of them?

Comment: Right now you bind the onclick event to document.ready. So when the page is rendered it is going to find all the elements that exist at that time, and run your bindings. When you click a button, and create new HTML, that extra HTML was not in the DOM at the time of the original binding. So to add an on click event to that new HTML, it needs to have the binding event triggered after the HTML is generated... And yes, you would need a unique id for every element on the page, otherwise you should use classes. ID's should always be a way to identify a unique element in the DOM.